# Different result when run io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r) consecutively in Golang

Tags: go

I am playing around Golang. About io.Copy
I put 2 consecutive io.Copy in the code, but i expect it output twice result(testtesttest). But the 2nd one is nil. Can anyone help explain why? tks

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "fmt"

)

type testReader struct {
    w io.Reader
    str string

}


func (tt *testReader) Read (b []byte) (n int, err error) {


    io.Copy(os.Stdout, tt.w)
     n, err = tt.w.Read(b)
     if tt.w !=nil {
        return 0,io.EOF
      }
    return
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("testtesttest!!!")
    r := testReader{s,"ttthhh"}
    fmt.Println(&r)
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
//  s.Seek(0,0)   // solution from Poy's answer
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)

}
```

Comment: Sorry for the noise of scripts. I will remove them to make it a bit clean

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to prune down the given example to (as there is a bit of noise):

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("testtesttest")
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, s) // Will print "testtesttest"
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, s) // Won't print anything
}
```

The reason the second copy won't output anything is the `io.Reader` (`s`) has already been read. Reading from a `io.Reader` is not idempotent (you can't call it twice to get the same results). <s>It also doesn't have a way to "reset" it or anything.</s>

As @JRLambert pointed out you have [s.Seek()](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Reader.Seek) and [s.Reset()](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Reader.Reset) to allow you to start reading again.

Comment: The reader returned from `strings.NewReader` implements the `Seeker` interface so you can call `s.Seek(0, 0)` to start reading at the beginning.

Comment: @JRLambert you're totally right I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks Poy.  Appreciate your answer. I will clean my script to make it a bit clean

Answer (score 0):

Quick addition to all the correct answers (@poy and @JRLambert) provided so far... Use `io.TeeReader` or `io.MultiWriter` for times when you would want to use `io.Copy` more than once. Below are [some examples of using each](https://gist.github.com/brydavis/a0cd1db30c8b84e8594a81b14dba7174).

**Using `io.TeeReader`**

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    sourceFile, _ := os.Open("source/ebook.pdf")

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    tee := io.TeeReader(sourceFile, &buf)

    process := func(sourceReader io.Reader) {
        targetFile, _ := os.Create("target/ebook.pdf")
        defer targetFile.Close()
        if _, err := io.Copy(targetFile, sourceReader); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }

    process(tee)
    fmt.Println(checksum(&buf))
}

func checksum(buf *bytes.Buffer) string {
    h := md5.New()
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(buf)
    if _, err := h.Write(b); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil)[:16])
}
```

**Using `io.MultiWriter`**

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    sourceFile, _ := os.Open("source/ebook.pdf")

    process := func(sourceReader io.Reader) {
        targetFile, _ := os.Create("target/ebook.pdf")
        defer targetFile.Close()

        var buf1, buf2 bytes.Buffer
        w := io.MultiWriter(targetFile, &buf1, &buf2)

        if _, err := io.Copy(w, sourceReader); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(checksum(&buf1))
        fmt.Println(checksum(&buf2))
    }

    process(sourceFile)

}

func checksum(buf *bytes.Buffer) string {
    h := md5.New()
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(buf)
    if _, err := h.Write(b); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil)[:16])
}
```